# App inventor: How to move sprite as long as button is pressed?

Tags: game-development, app-inventor

I recently wanted to develop a Brick Braker game in App inventor. But I keep coming across the same problem again and again. I'm trying to get the sprite to move as long as the button is pressed, so the longer the button is pressed the further the sprite moves, in ten steps. How do I do that? So far i only managed to get the sprite to move 10 pixels with every single click, but it would be stupid if you have to spamm the button all the time.

Comment: you already received several answers in the App Inventor community here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/app-inventor-how-do-i-move-a-sprite-as-long-as-button-is-pressed/22032?u=taifun

Comment: Yeah, I did not think that the forum was so active...Thanks :D